# lite app and full app - best practise for dividing?

Tags: eclipse, coding-style

What is the best practise for developing a lite app and a full app with additional features? It is better to create 2 projects in eclipse oder just one project with e.g a constant for switching the functionality? I think there are advantages and disadvantages for both approaches: With 2 projects you always have to do everything twice if you update your apps, with only one project the app is larger then needed. 
 I didn't find much about this topic, so I ask you, what is your approach or do you know some articles explaining solutions?

At least, I found this:
http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/08/05/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/

Any more approaches/ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of Android development, but in general I would move all the real code to one or more library projects and then reference that from specific projects that can take a "pick-and-mix" to assemble differently capabable applciations.

Taking that a step further component technologies like OSGi allow you to pull together arbitrary selections of components as specified in a configuration file.